# Enumeration not from 1

Tags: org-mode

When I have an enumeration sequence like so:

```
   57. y = alloc(30)
   58. z = alloc(40)
   59. t = alloc(25)
```

org-mode keeps setting the numbers down to 1, 2, 3, unless I'm really careful and don't touch any “electric” keys. Is there any way to prevent that, telling org-mode that I really want this enumeration to start from 57?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will do the trick:

57. [@57] y = alloc(30)
58. z = alloc(40)
59. t = alloc(25)

The `[@57]` is a [special keyword](http://orgmode.org/manual/Plain-lists.html#fnd-4) for forcing the current list item counter.

Comment: Thanks. I feel like I should have found that in the documentations, but I didn't.